How can $L_x$ be an observable?
I'm working with the orbital angular momentum operator $L_x$, and I don't quite understand how it can represent an observable. Using ladder operators, I can write $L_x$ as:
$$L_x=\frac{1}{2}(L_++L_-)$$
But if I do this, then I get as a result that the spherical harmonics are not eigenfunctions of my operator, since the ladder operators evidently do not allow for it (I can't get an eigenfunction such that $L_x|l,m\rangle=\alpha |l,m\rangle$). Therefore, how can I know the possible values $L_x$ can adopt as an observable?

Can you apply $L_+$ and $L_-$ to $|m\rangle$ ($l$ isn't necessary), so we don't have to look it up?

$\hat{L}_x$ is Hermitian and hence has a complete set of eigenvectors, just like $\hat{L}_z$ does. (I mean, how could the $z$-component be somehow more special than the $x$-component?) There are spherical harmonics that are eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}_x$: they're the $z$-spherical harmonics rotated so that the $z$-axis becomes the $x$-axis. But these new spherical harmonics are then not eigenvectors of $\hat{L}_z$; they can't be, because $\hat{L}_z$ and $\hat{L}_x$ don't commute.

@march That should be an answer instead of a comment.

@VincentThacker I often try to post comments first to make sure that I understand what the OP is actually confused about. For instance, here, I thought that this was the answer to the question, but it might actually have been about the fact that $L_+$ and $L_-$ don't have complete sets of eigenvectors, and so how could $L_x$ if it's the sum of those two?  I suppose I should make it more clear in my comments that I'm actually asking a question of sorts rather than stating an answer. A "Can you clarify?" or something. It's moot anyway, because there is now an accepted answer!

The spherical harmonics are simultaneous eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}^2$ and $\hat{L}_z$, so they won't be eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}_x$ (since $\hat{L}_z$ and $\hat{L}_x$ don't commute). This doesn't mean that there aren't any eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}_x$. In fact, since the labeling of the coordinate axes is arbitrary, you can just choose coordinates $x', y', z'$ in which the $z'$-axis is the same as the $x$-axis. Then you'll have spherical harmonics that are eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}^2$ and $\hat{L}_{z'}$, which is the same thing as having eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}_x$. This tells you that the spectrum of eigenvalues of $\hat{L}_x$ is the same as for $\hat{L}_z$.
